# Neural network for a data with 5 inputs and 1 output of 3 different types

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a `neural network` for my data which is as follows

```
Close   label   returns lag_1   lag_2   lag_3   lag_4   lag_5
Date                                
2007-09-26 00:00:00 4940.500000 1   0.000334    0.001348    0.019566    0.018957    0.003212    0.040946
2007-09-27 00:00:00 5000.549805 1   0.012155    0.000334    0.001348    0.019566    0.018957    0.003212
2007-09-28 00:00:00 5021.350098 1   0.004160    0.012155    0.000334    0.001348    0.019566    0.018957
2007-10-01 00:00:00 5068.950195 1   0.009480    0.004160    0.012155    0.000334    0.001348    0.019566
2007-10-03 00:00:00 5210.799805 1   0.027984    0.009480    0.004160    0.012155    0.000334    0.001348
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2010-09-24 00:00:00 6018.299805 0   0.009858    -0.005250   -0.003004   0.004782    0.016228    0.009651
2010-09-27 00:00:00 6035.649902 0   0.002883    0.009858    -0.005250   -0.003004   0.004782    0.016228
2010-09-28 00:00:00 6029.500000 0   -0.001019   0.002883    0.009858    -0.005250   -0.003004   0.004782
2010-09-29 00:00:00 5991.299805 0   -0.006336   -0.001019   0.002883    0.009858    -0.005250   -0.003004
2010-09-30 00:00:00 6029.950195 0   0.006451    -0.006336   -0.001019   0.002883    0.009858    -0.005250
```

For the NN, lag_(1 to 5) are the inputs and label is the output.
label can have -1,0 and 1 as values.

My current NN is based on `MLPClassifier`

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
model = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, max_iter=500,
                               hidden_layer_sizes=5 * [10], random_state=1)
```

It is working as expected and is providing me with the worst results. The only prediction it gives is 0 and rarely any 1 or -1.

Is there any way in which it doesn't predict only -1,0 and 1, but predicts a `float value between [-1,1]` like 0.123,-0.69,0.420?

**If there are other implementations of NN which are better for this situation, then please feel free to use them.**

Comment: I wonder if MLPClassifier can do non binary classification (output classes > 2). You may have a look at grov answer to use a regression instead. Also, don't forget to normalize your inputs that seem very small.  Last point is it could be worth checking if the proportions of class - 1, 0 and 1 are not unbalanced in your dataset. If you have a lot of 0 values in your dataset, the network will have a tendency to always return 0 since it is the most frequent answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a regression model (which produces a real value as the output, e.g. a value in the range `[-1, 1]` but possibly outside as well depending on the learning algorithm) instead of a classification model (which produces one of a set of discrete output values based on the training data, e.g. `{-1, 0, 1}` in your case).

If the code is changed to use [MLPRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) instead of [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), it will provide a real value as output.

Instead of:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
model = MLPClassifier(...)
```

Use:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
model = MLPRegressor(...)
```